# An automated way to load multiple images into PowerPoint on different pages?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I need to load about 60 images, each on a different page, in to PowerPoint.

Does anyone know of an "automated" way to do this. I don't want to go through slide by slide, and have to click "load image" on each one.

If it was a one-time thing, I wouldn't worry about it, but we're summarizing results from some analysis that is ongoing and we'll have to do it many times.

Thanks.

edit: After brief discussion with co-worker, it seems that "insert -> photo album" does this easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [PPTools](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00050.htm): Insert -> Photo Album works well in PPT 2007. There are a few Problems in older Versions, because the images are linked, not embedded if you do not choose the right settings.

The site mentioned above also [features a macro](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00352.htm) for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of open source programs, both hosted on sourceforge.net, which were developed for just the situation you describe.  They are:

[Powerpoint Picture Insert Command Line Interface](http://p3icli.sourceforge.net/) (a console program), also known as P3ICLI.

There's also a GUI wrapper for P3ICLI, called Powerpoint Picture Insert, or P3I for short (I can't link to it due to forum posting restrictions).  If you want to use the GUI, you must also install P3ICLI.

=================

FWIW, my wife invokes P3ICLI from JMP (a stats package) to dump multiple graphs into a single PPT presentation...no point and clicking required.