# Programmatically add an image to a PowerPoint file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to programmatically add an image to a PowerPoint file?

1. Create the file, open the file
2. Add the image
3. Close the file

I need to do this to about 1000 PowerPoint files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar was answered in the past:
[An automated way to load multiple images into PowerPoint on different pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469424/an-automated-way-to-load-multiple-images-into-powerpoint-on-different-pages)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into using FileSystemObject here to run Otaku's code for each file in a specific directory

```
Dim objFSO As Object, objFile As Object, strPath As String, p as Presentation

strPath = "C:\Wherever\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strPath) Then
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(strPath).Files
        If InStr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), ".JPG") + _
            InStr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), ".GIF") + _
            InStr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), ".PNG") + _
            InStr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), ".BMP") > 0 Then
            '# use Otaku's code above to add a presentation, the image, then close
            Set p = Presentations.Add(msoFalse)
            With p
                .Slides.Add Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank
                .Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=strPath & objFile.Name, _
                    LinktoFile:=msoFalse, _
                    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=10, Top:=10
                 .SaveAs strPath & Left(objFile.Name, InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".") - 1)
                 .Close
            End With
            Set p = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Question: Why do you bother to use InStr to check the extension? Why not just use the File objects Type property? Otherwise nice clean code (apart from the late bound call to FSO!) great work.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can use something like this from within PowerPoint:

```
Sub CreatePresWithImage()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim savePath As String
    imagePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\My Documents\My Pictures\"
    savePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\My Documents\"
    Dim p As Presentation
    For i = 0 To 999
        Set p = Presentations.Add(msoFalse)
        With p
            .Slides.Add Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank
            .Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagePath & "HueTint-30.png", _
                                            LinktoFile:=msoFalse, _
                                            SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=10, Top:=10
            .SaveAs savePath & "Sample" & i + 1
            .Close
        End With
        Set p = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

You'll need to manage the picture portion (in `.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=` above) to ensure you're getting the pictures you want each time. In that same routine, you can set the picture size (`Width` and `Height` - they're optional) and location (`Left` and `Top`).